# echo js not loading all images

Tags: javascript, lazy-loading

I am trying to use owl carousel and echo.js for image carousel and and lazy loading.

Now the problem is only some of the images are loaded in the carousel. say 7 out of 10 is loading remaining 3 the echo js is not loading the image.

Why is this happening?

here is my code

```
<div id="brand-slider" class="owl-carousel brand-slider custom-carousel owl-theme">
            <div class="item">
                <a href="#" class="image">
                    <img data-echo="assets/images/brands/univers.jpg" src="assets/images/blank.gif" alt="">
                </a>    
            </div><!--/.item-->

            <div class="item">
                <a href="#" class="image">
                    <img data-echo="assets/images/brands/kelloggs.jpg" src="assets/images/blank.gif" alt="">
                </a>    
            </div><!--/.item-->

            <div class="item">
                <a href="#" class="image">
                    <img data-echo="assets/images/brands/pampers.jpg" src="assets/images/blank.gif" alt="">
                </a>    
            </div><!--/.item-->

            <div class="item">
                <a href="#" class="image">
                    <img data-echo="assets/images/brands/pepsico.jpg" src="assets/images/blank.gif" alt="">
                </a>    
            </div><!--/.item-->

            <div class="item">
                <a href="#" class="image">
                    <img data-echo="assets/images/brands/p-g.jpg" src="assets/images/blank.gif" alt="">
                </a>    
            </div><!--/.item-->

            <div class="item">
                <a href="#" class="image">
                    <img data-echo="assets/images/brands/vini.jpg" src="assets/images/blank.gif" alt="">
                </a>    
            </div><!--/.item-->

            <div class="item">
                <a href="#" class="image">
                    <img data-echo="assets/images/brands/itc.jpg" src="assets/images/blank.gif" alt="">
                </a>    
            </div><!--/.item-->

            <div class="item">
                <a href="#" class="image">
                    <img data-echo="assets/images/brands/nestle.jpg" src="assets/images/blank.gif" alt="">
                </a>    
            </div><!--/.item-->

            <div class="item">
                <a href="#" class="image">
                    <img data-echo="assets/images/brands/cadbury.jpg" src="assets/images/blank.gif" alt="">
                </a>    
            </div><!--/.item-->

            <div class="item">
                <a href="#" class="image">
                    <img data-echo="assets/images/brands/coco.jpg" src="assets/images/blank.gif" alt="">
                </a>    
            </div><!--/.item-->

            <div class="item">
                <a href="#" class="image">
                    <img data-echo="assets/images/brands/kraft.jpg" src="assets/images/blank.jpg" alt="">
                </a>    
            </div><!--/.item-->

 </div><!-- /.owl-carousel #logo-slider -->
```

Comment: Please paste your code in your question. Edit it.

Comment: edited and pasted in the question

Answer (score 0):

according to the docs [here](http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/) the default max of items is 5. So you need to set it to what you want. Like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {     
  $("#brand-slider").owlCarousel({
      items : 10     
  });     
});
```

Other examples of how to do this can be found [here](http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/demos/images.html)

Comment: I found the answer `echo.init({
            offset: 1000,
            throttle: 250,
            unload: false
        });`

Comment: I can use the offset to target images off the viewport.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.

```
 echo.init({
        offset: 1000,
        throttle: 250,
        unload: false
    });
```

we can use the offset parameter of the echo js to target the the images off the viewport.